# UIColor to unsigned integer

Tags: iphone, ios

I found a category for `UIImage` for replacing color [here](https://gist.github.com/1292152)

The problem is that the method signature receives an unsigned integer color code:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByRemovingColorsWithMinColor:(uint)minColor maxColor:(uint)maxColor
```

How do I get proper unsigned integer value from a `UIColor`?

I actually want to replace black color with purple.

Comment: it was very bad choice from the author to convert the `UIColor` to `unsigned int`, because the `UIColor` is working with `float` between `0.0` and `1.0` and it aligns the current colour for the current output. to convert `float` numbers into one `unsigned int` might cause a simple data loss. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you had looked at the sources, you would have found out that they use this unsigned integer value as a hexadecimal color code, where

```
colorcode = ((unsigned)(red * 255) << 16) + ((unsigned)(green * 255) << 8) + ((unsigned)(blue * 255) << 0)
```

So you can get such a hexadecimal value from an UIColor object using someting like this:

```
@implementation UIColor (Hex)

- (NSUInteger)colorCode
{
    float red, green, blue;
    if ([self getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:NULL])
    {
        NSUInteger redInt = (NSUInteger)(red * 255 + 0.5);
        NSUInteger greenInt = (NSUInteger)(green * 255 + 0.5);
        NSUInteger blueInt = (NSUInteger)(blue * 255 + 0.5);

        return (redInt << 16) | (greenInt << 8) | blueInt;
    }

    return 0;
}

@end
```

And then use it like:

```
NSUInteger hexPurple = [[UIColor purpleColor] colorCode];
```

Comment: **+1**, I like your first sentence. :)

Comment: i did have a look and it went all over my head. P.S. I am not even a graduate yet =) let me test your code. I think it should work

Comment: @holex thanks! :) I tend to do it for some kind of an educational purpose. Here OP really should have made a little effort to get to know what the code does.

Comment: @tGilani I'm not even in university yet :-) (see my profile).

Comment: @H2CO3 your experience exceeds far mine. however the xcode is giving an error .. Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'int') on the line `return (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;` underlining green identifier and 8 literal .. !!

Comment: perhaps you intended .. `return (redInt << 16) + (greenInt << 8) + blueInt;`

Comment: @tGilani lemme see it! Ah so I overlooked it and made a mistake. See edit.

Comment: @tGilani yes of course! (You see you can see the good solution at first glance if you search a bit for it? :-)

Comment: =D one last thing. Is it | or + as my proposition is different from your edit.

Comment: @tGilani it's absolutely indifferent :) | means bitwise OR which is equivalent to addition if you shift the bytes next to each other :)

Comment: Why do you do this: red * 255 + 0.5? Why do you add 0.5?

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on 64 bit iOS. To fix change float to CGFloat. Tried editing the answer but it was rejected.